# Are there any best practices to use environments in telegram bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have several telegram bots which are running on production.

But also I have to develop new features at the same time. Are there any best practices to use environments (like development, test and production) in telegram bots, that will allow me to develop and test new features without corrupting stable versions behaviour?

I am using python3 and python-telegram-bot library.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use several instances of your bot - one for development and
   tests, one for production. When you done with new features in
   development branch - build and run it and stop your production bot at the
   same time. If you satisfied with development version run it on production.
2. You can copy your code from production bot and create new bot and work with it in development and tests.